# Running some java code on a client from a server

Tags: java, rmi

I am wondering how this is done.Suppose i have a client application and it has this method `restartMachine();`
How can i make this method to execute on the client from the server?.

Comment: You'd have to get the client to ask the server for "things" to do. It would get them and then act on them. Erm presumably the user running the client is okay with you restarting the machine????

Comment: The client is okay if i restart the machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually you will use protocols like IIOP, which delivers [CORBA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RMI-IIOP). this will allow for an interface, or a contract, to define common object structures between the server and the client.

See the [specs on OMG](http://www.omg.org/spec/) for further reading.